# deserialize json object does not work

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I want to deserialize my json object to my student class

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(data);
```

My json data

```
{  
"student":{  
  "fname":"997544",
  "lname":"997544",
  "subject":"IT",
  "grade":"F"
}
}
```

My student class

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    [JsonProperty("fname")]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lname")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("grade")]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
 }
```

The code does not work, the error says:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: That is not a valid Json string, are you missing a closing `}`?

Comment: @DavidG just a typing error  i edited it

Comment: [Serializable] public class Player
    {  [JsonProperty("fname")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Cells")]
        public List<int> Cells { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Level")]
        public string Level { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class PlayerDef
    { public Player Player { get; set; }  }
{  "Player" :
  {    "FirstName": "Foo",
    "LastName": "Fighter",
    "Cells": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ],
    "Level": "46"
  }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have to use your downloaded json then you need to create another model 
class for it

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    [JsonProperty("fname")]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lname")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("grade")]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class NewModel
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

then deserialize

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewModel>(data);
```

Comment: @Mostafiz, i donload the json in this format , i cant change

Comment: @Mostafiz since all my json object have the same format , how can i make it  generic

Comment: all start with `"student":{  ` or anything other ?

Comment: @Mostafiz make the NewModel class generic like public class NewModel:<T> where T : class
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

Comment: you can use anonymous type deserialization for that case http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON string currently represents an object with an **inner object property** named Student. If you want to deserialize to your Student object your JSON string should look like this:

```
{  
   "fname":"997544",
   "lname":"997544",
   "subject":"IT",
   "grade":"F"
}
```

If it's not easy to change your JSON you could also use JObject to help you like so:

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
var student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(jobject["student"].ToString());
```

Or as others have pointed out you can simply create another class wrapper and deserialize directly to that.

Answer (score 2):

You JSON object is inside a nameless **Root / Parent** Object.

So Use something like the following.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
```

then your `Student` instance can be access as `result.student`

Ex:

```
string firstName = result.student.FirstName;
```

I use Json2CSharp to generate the additional `RootObject` class.

Here's all the class definitions

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    [JsonProperty("fname")]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lname")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("grade")]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
 }

[Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public Student student { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to deal with the object from JSON, it's easiest to start with

```
var jStudent = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
```

You can then go to any sub property of the JObject through key reference and deserialize as you're expecting.

```
var student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(jStudent["student"].ToString());
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot change your Json string, you need to modify your class structure to match it. Note that the `student` object is wrapped in another class. The class structure to use this Json data looks like this:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [JsonProperty("fname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("grade")]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialise like this:

```
var wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(data);
```